# Ошибка string indices must be integers в программе Python

Tags: python

пишу программу на Python, в которой нужно ввести строку и слово, и заменить самое короткое слово в строке на введенное слово.
'''

```
st=str(input('enter string: ').split())
wr=str(input('enter word: '))
res = []
count = 100
n = 1
for i in st:
    if len(i)<count:
        count=len(i)
        word=i 
        n = i
        
for i in st:
    if len(i) == n:
        res.append(wr)
    else:
        res.append(st[i])

        


print(res)
```

'''
В строке res.append мне выводится эта ошибка, хотя непонятно, потому что i и есть int.

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ то пожалуйста примите его

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего проблема здесь

```
st=str(input('enter string: ').split())
```

Если ввести `привет друг` то мы получим строку

```
"['привет', 'друг']"
```

а нам нужен массив поэтому уберите `str`

```
st = input('enter string: ').split()
```

а также у вас не правильно содержимое второго цикла `for`

```
if len(i) == count:
    res.append(wr)
else:
    res.append(i)
```

Comment: Правда, проблема решена!